# Carbon rim white after applying Gorilla super gel glue - cause for concern?

Tags: rims, carbon, rim-tape

[image]

Rode over a big nail the other day which not only went through the (tubeless) tyre, but also made a significant hole in the rim.

Before retaping the rum, I applied Gorilla super gel glue yesterday to stop up the hole.

When I came home from a ride today, I saw that the rim was white around the glue.

Is this cause for concern?

Comment: Super Glue (cyanoacrylate) shouldn’t damage carbon fiber composites. I would have used epoxy for the repair. Is there a clear coat on the rim? Maybe there are some solvents in the glue which attacked the clear coat (but shouldn’t harm carbon fiber). Or the white stuff is a thin film of the glue.

Comment: What's a good way of removing "the white" before retaping?

Comment: I would leave it as it is. If there is clear coat on it you could use some fine sandpaper.

Answer (score 2):

The glue you have used has reacted with either the clearcoat on the rim or the resin used in construction (whatever is the top layer).

The reaction has clearly stopped now so it isn't going to get worse by itself but if you were being sensible you would have the area fixed properly, perhaps by a fibre repair specialist using the proper resins. An extra hole in the rim might not seem to matter too much but you can't see inside the rim section to see the nail hasn't damaged the layup structure.

Answer (score 2):

Cyanoacrylate adhesives frequently leave a whitish residue when curing in an area without much air ventilation. I've seen this many times when using cyanoacrylates in enclosed areas on different kinds of surfaces.  It's a residue, not a reaction, so there are no harmful effects (other than the appearance).